# Convert array of json objects into json

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, select, unnest

In a postgres table I have some jsonb in this format

```
[{"type": "pet", "animal": "cat"}, {"type": "farm", "animal": "cow","colour": "brown"}]
```

But I want to turn it into this format

```
{"cat": {"type": "pet", "animal": "cat"}, "cow" {"type": "farm", "animal": "cow", "colour": "brown"}
```

And I can't figure it out or find anyone on the internet who has jsonb in this format. Can anyone solve this? Ideally the sets of data that don't have a key/value for "colour" won't have {"colour": null} but just won't have the key "colour" at all

I'm on postgres 9.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option that works by unnesting the json array and reaggregating it into one object:

```
select x.new_js_col
from mytable t
cross join lateral (
    select jsonb_object_agg(obj ->> 'animal', to_jsonb(obj)) new_js_col
    from jsonb_array_elements(t.js_col) as x(obj)
) x(new_js_col)
```

This assumes that you have a jsonb column called `js_col` in table `mytable`.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b9aa990fe44d03d980c705e99727f8ed)**:

```
| new_js_col                                                                                             |
| :----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| {"cat": {"type": "pet", "animal": "cat"}, "cow": {"type": "farm", "animal": "cow", "colour": "brown"}} |
```